# Generic way to set values depending on indexes in ndarray?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I wrote this below but it looks ugly/clumsy to me.
Is there a better way to loop through all elements while keeping track of indexes
(i.e. keeping track at which address I am) and set a value which is a function
of the indexes?

I can imagine this getting even uglier if I have more dimensions.
There should be a better way designed to do just this.

```
import numpy as np

def f(i,j,k,l):
    return i + 2 * j+ 3 * k + 4 * l

A = np.zeros((3,4,7,8), dtype=int)

i1 = i2 = i3 = i4 = -1

i1 = -1
for r1 in A:
    i1 += 1

    i2 = -1
    for r2 in r1:
        i2 += 1

        i3 = -1
        for r3 in r2:

            i3 += 1

            i4 = -1
            for r4 in r3:
                i4 += 1

                v = f(i1, i2, i3, i4)

                print ("Setting value {0} at ({1}, {2}, {3}, {4})".format(v, i1, i2, i3, i4))

                A[i1, i2, i3, i4] = v

print(A)
```

Comment: The best way it avoid this element by element process.  Set aside some time to read the `numpy` basics to see how they are meant to be used.

Comment: @hpaulj Well, I am reading but I don't know if my sources are very good. Nowadays it's hard to tell which posts are good to read. Python is not my primary language. How to avoid it? What if I want the value to be a function of the indexes? Could you post a link or something?

Comment: I was thinking of the quickstart tutorial: https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/user/quickstart.html

Comment: If `f` is a generic function that only takes scalar index values, there isn't a shortcut.  There are a few things that make the loops prettier (like `np.ndenumerate`), but not anything that makes it faster.  To use `numpy` right you need to think of ways that work with whole arrays of indices, not just element by element.  Keep in mind that all subsequent used of the array will be slow if you have to iterate like this all the time.  `numpy` is the wrong if you have to do that.

Answer (score 2):

There is `np.fromfunction`:

```
np.fromfunction(f,(3,4,7,8),dtype=int)
```

This works as long as `f` is "numpy aware", i.e can handle array arguments.

Answer (score 0):

### Solving the problem with np.apply_along_axis manner

I break it down to a more easy example to explain the logic behind my idea and move on from that.

I want to use a combination of `np.indices` which returns a grid of indices of the given shape and `np.apply_along_axis` with which we can apply a function along a given axis of a multi-dimensional array.

Example:

```
def f(arr):
    return arr[0] + 2 * arr[1]

A=np.zeros((2,3))
```

Note that the input of the function `f` is changed since it's input is a np.array of shape `(4,)` and not 4-element tuple.

we will use

```
np.indices(A.shape)
```

to get the a grid of indices of matrix `A`.
We can easily apply the function as

```
np.apply_along_axis(f, axis=0, arr=np.indices(A.shape))
```

which results in

```
array([[0, 2, 4],    # 0 + 2*0, 0 + 2*1, 0 +2*2
       [1, 3, 5]])   # 1 + 2*0, 1 + 2*1, 1 +2*2
```

Now let's move to the example given by OP. The code is the same, we just exchange `f` and `A`

```
def f(arr):
   return arr[0] + 2 * arr[1]+ 3 * arr[2] + 4* arr[3]

A = np.zeros((3,4,7,8), dtype=int)
np.apply_along_axis(f, axis=0, arr=np.indices(A.shape))
```

Since the result is of shape `(3, 4, 7, 8)` I won't post it here.

### Timing results

`np.apply_along_axis` proves to be a lot slower than the manual iteration even for arrays of considerable size.

Here are some timing results:

```
shape            manual            np.apply_along_axis
100,100,100,10  4.18 s ± 39.7 ms     34.8 s ± 298 ms
100,100,10,10   412 ms ± 6.23 ms     3.49 s ± 13.4 ms
3,4,7,8         285 µs ± 1.79 µs     2.43 ms ± 35.6 µs
```

Comment: `apply_along_axis` should have a speed disclaimer; it doesn't avoid loops.  In other words, it isn't true `numpy` "vectorization".  And stay away from `np.vectorize`:too.

Answer (score 0):

Your `f`, at least this example, works with arrays, since it uses the numpy vectorized operators `+` and `*`.

```
def f(i,j,k,l):
    return i + 2 * j+ 3 * k + 4 * l
```

Using `np.ix_` to generate indices that can broadcast against each other, I can produce an array that matches your iterative `A`:

```
In [14]: A1 = f(*np.ix_(np.arange(3),np.arange(4),np.arange(7),np.arange(8)))                                   
In [15]: np.allclose(A,A1)                                                                                      
Out[15]: True
```

Now if `f` can work with arrays, we can't do this.  A classic example is one that uses `math.sin` instead of `np.sin`.  Or one that is `if` tests.

That `ix_` way is fast, since it calls `f` only once.  I can also generate all indices as tuples with `np.ndindex`, and call `f` many times:

```
In [24]: A2 = np.zeros_like(A)                                                                                  
In [25]: for ijk in np.ndindex(*A2.shape): A2[ijk]=f(*ijk)                                                      
In [26]: np.allclose(A,A2)                                                                                      
Out[26]: True
```

The speed will be similar to your `A` evaluation.

```
In [29]: %%timeit  
    ...: A2 = np.zeros_like(A) 
    ...: for ijk in np.ndindex(*A2.shape): A2[ijk]=f(*ijk)  
    ...:  
    ...:                                                                                                        
758 µs ± 11.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [30]: timeit A1 = f(*np.ix_(np.arange(3),np.arange(4),np.arange(7),np.arange(8)))                            
54.3 µs ± 2.44 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [31]: %%timeit 
    ...: A = np.zeros((3,4,7,8), dtype=int) 
    ...:  
    ...: i1 = i2 = i3 = i4 = -1 
    ...:  
    ...: i1 = -1 
    ...: for r1 in A: 
    ...:     i1 += 1 
    ...:  
    ...:     i2 = -1 
    ...:     for r2 in r1: 
    ...:         i2 += 1 
 ....
    ...:                 A[i1, i2, i3, i4] = v 
    ...:                                                                                                        
506 µs ± 2.03 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Come to think of it, we can clean up your loops with a more typical Python `range` loop:

```
In [35]: %%timeit 
    ...: A = np.zeros((3,4,7,8), dtype=int) 
    ...: for i1 in range(A.shape[0]): 
    ...:     for i2 in range(A.shape[1]): 
    ...:         for i3 in range(A.shape[2]): 
    ...:             for i4 in range(A.shape[3]): 
    ...:                 v = f(i1, i2, i3, i4) 
    ...:                 A[i1, i2, i3, i4] = v 
    ...:                                                                                                        
343 µs ± 17.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```